# Storing data on button click using background thread and sqlite

Tags: android, multithreading, sqlite, android-asynctask

**[solved]**
*I've redesigned the whole thing a bit: got rid of the singleton pattern, created method that inserts the values and made doInBackground() call it.*

I have an activity with 2 forms and a button in it. So when the button is clicked, the info is stored in sqlite database and once it's done, the button sets disabled. I'm using SQLiteOpenHelper and AsyncTask to get it done.
My questions: where should I instantiate my DB? What am I missing, is there a better way to do all of this?

**DatabaseHelper:**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper  {

private static DatabaseHelper singleton=null;

synchronized static DatabaseHelper getInstance(Context context) {
    if (singleton == null) {
        singleton = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }
    return singleton;
}

private DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DBContract.DATABASE_NAME, null, DBContract.SCHEMA_VER);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    try {
        db.beginTransaction();
        db.execSQL(DBContract.WordTable.CREATE_TABLE);
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    }
    finally {
        db.endTransaction();
    }
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
}

public void saveWord(String theWord, String translatedWord) {
    ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();

    newValues.put(DBContract.WordTable.THEWORD_COLUMN, theWord);
    newValues.put(DBContract.WordTable.TRANSLATED_COLUMN, translatedWord);

    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(DBContract.DATABASE_NAME, null, newValues);
    }
}
```

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private DatabaseHelper dbhelper;
private EditText wordField, translatedField;
private Button addButton;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    DatabaseHelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

    wordField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.word_title);
    translatedField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.translated_title);
    addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addword_button);

    addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new WordSaveTask().execute(wordField.getText().toString(),translatedField.getText().toString());
        }
    });

}

private class WordSaveTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        dbhelper.saveWord(params[0], params[1]);

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        addButton.setEnabled(false);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: If the DatabaseHelper is wrapped within a singleton, there's no need to have an instance of it at class level in your MainActivity. Also, it doesn't seem like you're calling getInstance anywhere in your MainActivity. Lastly, you might want to put a `synchronized` keyword next to your method signature: `synchronized public void ...`. This helps when you have more than one thread accessing the database.

Comment: I added  `DatabaseHelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext())` to onCreate() method in MainActivity, but once I press the button it gets me thrown out of the app.

Comment: Paste the error. Tell us what errors you're getting and what you've tried so we know more.

Comment: Added the errorlog in the post.

Comment: Does that even compile? When extending `AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>` your `doInBackground()` method must have `String... params` and not `Void... params`.

Comment: It compiles, I've mistyped it in here. How to make it worK?

Comment: There is no need to use singleton pattern. Result of the getInstance() call is not assigned to dbHeleper member.